# How to create log file with rotate option in CakePHP 2.1.5

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I found following code in CakePHP 2.5.1 `lib/Cake/Log/Engine/FileLog.php` which crate log file with `rotate` option.

```
protected $_defaults = array(
        'path' => LOGS,
        'file' => null,
        'types' => null,
        'scopes' => array(),
        'rotate' => 10,
        'size' => 10485760, // 10MB
        'mask' => null,
    );
```

But, My question is how to create log file with rotate option in `CakePHP 2.1.5` ?

Answer (score 0):

[The manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#creating-and-configuring-log-streams), if you read it, tells you clearly that this is:

> New in version 2.4.

So you *can't* use it in 2.1 except it was backported (which I doubt) or you'll have to backport it yourself.